# Phabricator, haw to take all tasks from database

Tags: php, phabricator

I use Conduit API to create gantt chart for phabricator application. I call maniphest.search method but I have an error when I want to take more than 100 tasks.

```
Maximum page size for Conduit API method calls is 100, but this call specified 101.
```

Why? Haw Can I take all tasks? (or more than 100)

Thanks for reply.

@UPDATE:

1. First solution it is possible by maniphest.search method
2. Second solution is a loop like below - Ugly (bad practice - but you can get all nessesery fields)

   for($i=0; $i <= 700; $i=$i+100){

   ```
   try {

       $result = $conduit->searchManiphest(
           [
               'queryKey'    => $this->getParameter('phacility_maniphest_query_key'),
               'attachments' => [
                   'projects' => TRUE,
                   'subscribers' => TRUE,
                   'columns' => TRUE,
                   'constraints' => TRUE,
               ],
               'order' => "newest",
               'after' => $i,
               'limit' => 100
           ]
       );

   } catch (\Exception $e) {
       $result = ['data' => []];
   }

   foreach($result['data'] as $item){
       $all_result['data'][] = $item;
   }
   ```

   }